# Is it possible to add superscript characters in the subject?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to find a way to add a superscript character in the text of a subject. Is it possible? If yes, does it affect the reputation of the email as being considered as a special character?

Comment: I presume you mean superscript?

Comment: Yes sorry, I was not sure how is it called in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.

Here's one [Superscript Generator](https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator) you can use to create and test it out.

Similar question was in stack few years ago - [Superscript in Gmail.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/111943/small-letters-in-superscript-in-gmail-subject-line)

Potentially useful [Litmus discussion](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/488-best-method-for-superscripts) on methods of using it.

There shouldn't be any changes related to Email Sender reputation from using it as far as I know.